# provided that VS. providing

Tags: conjunctions

It would be greatly appreciated if somebody could throw a light into if there is any difference between these? It would be necessary that I mention the fact that I know we could omit "that". Just my specific question is about only the following.

provided that

providing

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Are you trying to use these in a specific context?

**Provided that** is the one that's more often used as a conjunction.It means that one thing happening is dependent on another thing happening.

> I will come visit you provided that my car gets new tires.
>
> Provided that this project succeeds, I will get a promotion.

Sometimes people drop the **that** and only use **provided** and it means the same thing.

> Mark will come to the wedding provided Alice is not there.

**Providing** is usually a form of the verb **to provide** and means to supply/give.

> He is providing the food.

I don't know if **providing that** is used a conjunction. Maybe some places? It's not in American English as far as I know.

Comment: You can write your examples with *providing* instead of *provided that*

Answer (score 3):

They are synonyms, you can replace them in a sentence.

> I will come visit you **provided that** my car gets new tires.
>
> I will come visit you **providing** my car gets new tires.

Comment: Just a short note: *that* is optional in both *provided (that)* and *providing (that)*. [English Grammar Today](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/conditionals-other-expressions-unless-should-as-long-as) notes that *Providing (that)* is more common in speaking; *provided (that)* is more formal and more common in written language.

Answer (score 0):

Both providing (that) and provided (that) can be used. The oxford book has even the following sentence written in it.. 
I'll come with you providing that Bill doesn't mind.